# How to import Swagger Config

Tags: java, swagger

**Background**

I am running into some Swagger config issues, so I am trying to fix them by copying some simple example's configs.

I am reading this tutorial:
http://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api

And they have this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {                                    
    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
          .select()                                  
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())              
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
          .build();                                           
    }
}
```

**Setup**

I used to have this bean Docket in my `public class Application` But they seem to have the  configuration in its own class. I want to match their setup, So I made a SwaggerConfiguration.java file in the same place as my Application.java.

Then I made the SwaggerConfiguration.java contain the following code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Docket Api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .pathMapping("/")
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }


    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("Service API")
            .build();
    }
}
```

My Application.Java contains this code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableSwagger2
@ComponentScan({"myproject.request"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplication(Application.class).run(args);
    }

}
```

**Question:** How do I tie this SwaggerConfiguration.java into my project? (import it)

They do it here I believe: "Import the bean by adding the package name (if it’s missing) in the component-scan tag of the existing rest-dispatcher-servlet.xml" - http://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api

But, I don't have that serverlet nor do I have any xml file other than the pom.xml for maven.

**Question Rephrased**

My SwaggerConfig.java is just sitting in my project but not being used or imported by anything. `apiInfo` for instance isn't setting anything on the Swagger UI. How do I make it used.

**UPDATE 1**

There was a recommendation to remove `@ComponentScan({"myproject.request"})` but when i did my build failed and this was printed:

```
Description:

Field actionRepository in myproject.service.ActionServiceImpl required a bean of type 'myproject.repository.ActionRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'myproject.repository.ActionRepository' in your configuration.
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have changed SwaggerConfiguration to SwaggerConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    /*
    @Bean
    public Docket Api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("myproject.controller")).paths(regex("/api/*"))
                .build().apiInfo(apiInfo());

    }
    */
    @Bean
    public Docket Api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("ibm.controller"))
                .paths(regex("/api/*"))
                .build()
                .pathMapping("/")
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }


    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("Service API")
            .description("API for Service REST operations")
    }
}
```

But I have the same issues

**UPDATE 3 more background**

This problem is somewhat tied to this problem [Swagger no longer finds API controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46567907/swagger-no-longer-finds-api-controllers)

Comment: Try again after removing `@ComponentScan({"myproject.request"})` in Application. The annotation `@SpringBootApplication` should take care of all that.

Comment: @LucianovanderVeekens see my Update 1

Answer (score 4):

```
package com.vk.test.swagger;

import static springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors.regex;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2

/**
 * 
 * @author vaquar khan
 *
 */
public class SwaggerConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.vk.test.controller")).paths(regex("/api/apiPath.*"))
                .build();

    }

}
```

Maven

```
     <!-- Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Swagger UI -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Call swagger

```
http://<servername>:<Port>/swagger-ui.html
```

Comment: I cannot tell what you did differently from me other than rename `SwaggerConfiguration` to `SwaggerConfig` and use regex over `PathSelectors`. What am i missing?

Comment: basePackage("com.vk.test.controller")).paths(regex("/api/apiPath.*"))

Comment: should the ("/api/api‌​Path.*") be the ("myproject/controller") path or literally ("/api/api‌​Path.*")

Comment: no it should  be api URI  on controller like -                                        @RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/api‌​Path")
@Api(value = "onlinestore", description = "dgh kjgkj kbkjh ")

Comment: OK I have added your changes, but they do not seem to be "calling swagger" see Update 2

Comment: Plz add ur controller code